# Get more than an attribute's name and value in a dataset

Tags: c, hdf5

I have a dataset in a hdf5 file that has 4 attributes. [4 attributes with string type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHjOC.jpg)

How do I get each attribute name and its value?  I only know how to require the attribute numbers by the function  `int H5Aget_num_attrs( hid_t loc_id )`in the Website “ [function  website](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5A.html#Annot-NumAttrs)”

but I don't know how require the attributes name to a array by a function.

Any ideas?**best wishes!**

Comment: This question is impossible to understand. You should ask a specific question, like: I am trying to read some attributes from a file but `sscanf()` is failing. And post the code so others can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Oh, you want the name of an attribute?

You can't do that.

*~ Fin ~*

---

**EDIT 2:** This is because some function `xyzzy(sometype_t)` can only be passed one type -- therefore you know what the attributes are called.

---

I am going to attempt to find what your problem is.
If english is not your first language, no hard feelings. Otherwise, Please, please, please, **please** edit your question.

Anyway,

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b, c, d; /* four attributes.*/
} foo_t;

foo_t bar;
```

to get an attribute:

```
bar.a = 1;
bar.b = 2;
bar.c = 3;
bar.d = 4;
```

If you have a pointer...

```
foo_t * baz = &bar /* baz is a pointer to bar. */

baz->a = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the name of the (4) attributes and corresponding values stored in a dataset like this (in C using HDFql - http://www.hdfql.com):

```
char script[1024];

HDFQL_CURSOR my_cursor; // declare cursor named "my_cursor"

hdfql_initialize(&my_cursor); // initialize cursor "my_cursor"

hdfql_execute("USE FILE my_example.h5"); // use (i.e. open) HDF file named "my_example.h5"

hdfql_execute("SHOW my_dataset/"); // retrieve all (4) attributes stored in dataset "my_dataset"

while (hdfql_cursor_next(NULL) == HDFQL_SUCCESS) // loop through all attributes retrieved
{
    sprintf(script, "SELECT FROM my_dataset/%s", hdfql_cursor_get_char(NULL)); // prepare script to select (i.e. read) the content of the attribute

    hdfql_cursor_use(&my_cursor);

    hdfql_execute(script); // execute script

    hdfql_cursor_next(NULL);

    hdfql_cursor_use_default();

    printf("Attribute '%s' contains '%s'\n", hdfql_cursor_get_char(NULL), hdfql_cursor_get_char(&my_cursor));  // print the attribute name and its value
}
```